# Send and Receive USSD commands and responses via PHP

Tags: java, php, android, modem, ussd

I have an idea and I would like to be able to send USSD commands and receive USSD responses using a GSM SIM card via PHP.

Such as

Example Command

```
*555*
```

Example Response from GSM provider

```
1. Recharge Account
2. Send Credits
3. Service Menu
```

Example Reply Command

```
1
```

and the flow goes on.

Is this doable? What kind of hardware/modem do I need to get started? Can any one give me some tips?

Comment: A quick google search returned a PHP API called Ideamart that seems to be able to do what your asking.

Comment: You can use JOLO API https://joloapi.com/free_mobile_recharge_api.php

Comment: GSM modems usually have a serial interface for AT commands.

Comment: You can refer this link: http://www.ideamart.lk/idea-pro/ussd

Comment: Checkout this package https://github.com/mtvbrianking/laravel-ussd